# Unable to contact snap store

Tags: snap

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday. Today I tried to install micro editor through snap, but it doesn't work. Any command like this `sudo snap install hello-world` freezes for a minute and I receive

> error: unable to contact snap store

Is there some problem with the snap store or is it because I couldn't connect to it from my network? How could I check that?

Comment: Just got this myself. I was able to ping Google and login to snap, but find and install return this error.

Comment: Looks like they have some troubles with servers. Their [website](https://snapcraft.io/) is also very unstable in this moment.

Comment: Looks like it's working now (I was also getting the same erorr) - would recommend trying again!

Comment: this might be helpful https://status.snapcraft.io/

Answer (score 2):

Seems there might be a problem with the snap store this morning. Occasionally I get a successful return.

```
➜  ~ sudo snap find nextcloud
Name                Version           Developer     Notes  Summary
nextcloud-client    2.3.3+gitab40efe  nextcloud     -      Nextcloud Desktop Client
nextcloud-port8080  1.01              arcticslyfox  -      Nextcloud Server
nextcloud-nextant   11.0.0snap3       rmescandon    -      Nextcloud Server + search support
nextcloud           13.0.2snap1       nextcloud     -      Nextcloud Server - A safe home for all your data
cashbox-nextcloud   11.0.2snap2       cashbox       -      Nextcloud Server for www.cashBOX.plus
qownnotes           18.05.2           pbek          -      Plain-text file notepad with markdown support and ownCloud / Nextcloud integration
spreedme            0.29.5snap1       nextcloud     -      Spreed.ME audio/video calls and conferences feature for the Nextcloud Snap
solr                0.1               rmescandon    -      Starts up solr as forking daemon
mdns-hostname       0.0.1             welike        -      mDNS mini-daemon to published hostname.local
➜  ~ sudo snap find nextcloud
error: unable to contact snap store
➜  ~
```

Comment: I keep getting _error: unable to contact snap store_ from months, from any Linux virtual machine I create. I guess it's not simply a snap store problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error just now. A solution that worked for me was:

in terminal:

```
$ killall snap-store
```

Then the snap connection was back

Answer (score 0):

You might get that error when you are trying to install something through snap behind proxy.

Configure the proxy with these commands:

```
sudo snap set system proxy.http="http://<proxy_addr>:<proxy_port>"
sudo snap set system proxy.https="http://<proxy_addr>:<proxy_port>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Snap store might simply be down. Too bad this stalls. Refreshing snapd is supposed to fix this (?) according to a solution I saw, but it does not work because the web API is down. I don't know if the API spec changed, but it is currently the case that the host is not resolved. You have to wait until the store is back up. PS: There was probably a server change which takes time to propagate in my case.

```
$ sudo snap refresh snapd

error: cannot refresh "snapd": cannot refresh snap-declaration for "chromium":
       Get
       https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-declaration/16/XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R?max-format=4:
       dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host
$ host api.snapcraft.io
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```