# How to fix "unable to contact snap store" error while installing conjure-up

Tags: 16.04, snap, conjure-up

I am trying to install conjure-up to install the kubernetes on my ubuntu (16.04.1) with the command:

```
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
```

After a few seconds, the below error is shown:

```
error: unable to contact snap store
```

I have both http_proxy and https_proxy already setup

Below is the output from `snap version`

```
snap    2.34.2
snapd   2.34.2
series  16
ubuntu  16.04
kernel  4.15.0-42-generic
```

I came across the similar question, [Problem with snap store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034056/problem-with-snap-store) but the answer provided (issue with snap store try after some time) did not solve my issue.

Comment: Did you only set http_proxy as environment variable or did you also setup the snp proxy.http settings? As described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/764610/how-to-install-snap-packages-behind-web-proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 6):

Try configuring the proxy settings with these commands:

```
# sudo snap set system proxy.http="http://<proxy_addr>:<proxy_port>"
# sudo snap set system proxy.https="http://<proxy_addr>:<proxy_port>"
```

Comment: Snap is crap. I don't need a forward proxy on my web server so that people can log in as 'gameplayer' and play a game. Fortunately I can remove the proxy setting. Your answer should include how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `snap` and `snapd` files. It's working for me and I have tried many methods.

```
sudo apt purge snap
rm -rf ~/snap
sudo rm -rf /snap
sudo rm -rf /var/snap
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/snapd
sudo rm -rf /var/tmp/snapd.*
sudo rm -rf /etc/systemd/system/snapd.service.d
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install hello-world
```

I hope this will benefit you. :)