# How do I fix my connection to api.snapcraft.io

Tags: snap

While trying to upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 I get the following output:

> Connection to Snap Store failed
>
> Your system does not have a connection to the Snap Store. For the
> best upgrade experience make sure that your system can connect to
> api.snapcraft.io.
> Do you still want to continue with the upgrade?
>
> Continue [yN]

I would like to fix this before updating. I can find similar problems described online, but they all seem to be caused by snapcraft.io being temporarily down which is not the case right now according to [status.snapcraft.io](http://status.snapcraft.io/).

(*edit:* One of these similar problems is [Problem with snap store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034056/problem-with-snap-store) which is mentioned in the comments below as a possible duplicate, but as that question contains very little info it is difficult to know whether the problem is the same and no answers are given that are helpful in my case.)

If I try to run

```
snap install hello
```

I get

> net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
>
> error: unable to contact snap store

There is nothing wrong with my internet connection. `snap version` gives me

> snap    2.36.3
>
> snapd   2.36.3
>
> series  16
>
> ubuntu  16.04
>
> kernel  4.15.0-43-generic

Any ideas on what might be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with snap store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034056/problem-with-snap-store)

Comment: @N0bert: So this is one of the similar problems I mention where it seems that the problem was caused by snapcraft.io being down. But the error mentioned in that post is the same and the poster never accepted an answer. So what do I do when neither "That solved my problem" or "No, my question is different." really applies?

Comment: i fixed this by using an [external http proxy with snapd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764610/how-to-install-snap-packages-behind-web-proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: I keep getting _error: unable to contact snap store_. I don't think it's an issue with their server, so the answer on that question suggesting it was temporary isn't true.

Answer (score 13):

**For me it was a proxy problem:**

I couldn't remember that I set those (its funny how many places there are to set proxies...), but anyway clearing the proxies solved my problem when I changed to an environment without a proxy:

```
sudo snap set system proxy.http=""
sudo snap set system proxy.https=""
```

Comment: Pay attention to use the full url containing `http`, it will fail when missing. With `http://<proxy_addr>:<proxy_port>`: `error: cannot install "core": Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup
       api.snapcraft.io on 10.48.220.7:53: no such host
`, but it works with `http://<proxy_addr>:<proxy_port>`: `2021-12-02T13:15:57+01:00 INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...
core 16-2.52.1 from Canonical✓ installed
`

Comment: This answer worked for me when upgrading from 20.04 lts to v22.04 lts. I had to set my proxy settings directly for snap. My proxy environment variables weren't enough. Oddly enough, (after setting the proxy settings for snap) if I did a `snap refresh snapd` it reported that snapd wasn't installed, when it actually was. However, the upgrade worked and it connected properly to api.snapcraft.io. I later found this is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.4/+bug/1897972?comments=all) that has been out there for a few years.

Answer (score 6):

I also got the similar error while updating from 18.04.4 LTS to 20.04 LTS yesterday.

Following worked for me:

```bsh
snap refresh snapd
systemctl restart snapd
```

**Note:** If you get the error `snap snapd is not installed`, then first install **snapd** and then try executing above mentioned commands.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Same problem, same solution (thank you). I got the error `snap snapd is not installed` and tried to `apt get snapd`, which said it was already installed. So I ignored, typed `systemctl restart snapd` and tried again to upgrade. It worked.