# Unable to reinstall any Firefox (snap or apt) when upgrading from 18.04LTS to 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, firefox, snap

I upgraded a computer from Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS to 20.04 and then 22.04. During the process I had an error related to snap not able to connect to the server or something, but I did not care since I don't need/use snap packages...

...except that the upgrade process also requires changing Firefox from a traditional apt version to a snap version. So now I have no Firefox at all. I tried [following this to install the apt package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22) but it didn't work, probably because of this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 134.226.56.7 8080]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Now if I try to install with `apt` I get this:

```
> sudo apt install firefox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package firefox is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'firefox' has no installation candidate
```

If I try to install with `snap`:

```
> snap install firefox
error: cannot install "firefox": Post "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": proxyconnect
       tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

I'm lost, how can I get Firefox back? (preferably the apt version)

---

**Update: proxy**

This machine is behind a proxy. The proxy is configured as indicated in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1014978/109289) for `apt`, but `apt update` still has an error:

```
> sudo apt update
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease  
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 134.226.56.7 8080]
Fetched 109 kB in 7s (15.4 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 134.226.56.7 8080]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: @user535733 I'm not totally sure to be honest, but there was no similar error message asking me to abort or skip. all the regular apt packages have been successfully upgraded, so there was definitely access to the network.

Comment: is a proxy set in your system?

Comment: @nobody indeed, I'm behind a proxy. Afaik it's configured properly but I could be wrong, I updated the question.

Comment: For apt it seems correct set. Please try `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update` if possible.

Comment: @nobody I tried the command you suggested, no luck unfortunately.

Comment: @nobody by any chance, can you think of some config issue which would cause connection to the mozilla repository to fail but works with ubuntu regular repositories?

Comment: Nope sadly not. @Erwan

Answer (score 0):

I didn't succeed setting up the Mozilla repository so I wasn't able to install the `deb` version of Firefox.

However I eventually was able to install the `snap` version, it turns out it this problem was due to my proxy indeed (thanks to @nobody and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1294160/109289)):

```
sudo snap set system proxy.http="http://my-proxy"
sudo snap set system proxy.https="http://my-proxy"
```

Then snap was working:

```
snap install firefox
```