# Problem with snap store - unable to contact snap store

Tags: 18.04, snap

Facing similar to [Problem with snap store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034056/problem-with-snap-store).

I can search, but performing an installation is ending on *unable to contact snap store*.

[image: snap commands]

Below some details with pcap, but I did not find my answer there, any ideas?

[image: pcap]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).