# Problems with snap, after freshly reinstalling it ("unable to contact snap store")

Tags: 22.04, snap, snap-store

I recently installed **Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS** on my PC and have tried getting to know them, having a first experience of them.
After some time, *I realized that I, very commonly, ran into errors with the new, so-called, "Snap Store" of Ubuntu **(not "Ubuntu Software", this is another app)*** (the errors of "Snap Store" is a matter in itself). *That led me to try uninstalling it and the reinstalling it again, just in case that fixes the existing bugs. After one or two times, that worked.*

***The problem arised when I tried again, from my bash, the same procedure. Everything was going well with uninstalling and installing "snap", but at the point when "Snap Store" was to be installed, with "sudo snap install snap-store", I repeatedly got an error message, saying that the contact with snap store was not possible (the exact message was: "error: unable to contact snap store").***

I have tried many things, as well as, looked on the internet for solutions. I couldn't do anything...
Your help will be invaluable!

Thank you!

Comment: Run `snap debug connectivity` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @pzkpfw I ran it and got "PASS". I just have to tell, that, now, for some reason, snap works. I will leave the question open though in case it happens again, or happens something different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to contact snap store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034056/unable-to-contact-snap-store)

Comment: @karel To be truthful, I don't know how, but snap worked for me the next morning. I, just, let the question open, in case anyone knows anything additional that could help. I've seen that it is a common problem for the new Snap Store, but I didn't found any concrete solution. Thank you for your comment, though! I didn't check anything, 'cause I don't want my well-functioning Snap Store to be influenced, but I hope it could be of some help, if not none. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

I found this I don't know where.

Close all apps and open the terminal, type "killall snap-store" without the quotes.
Then open the snap store again.

Comment: Fount it here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034056/unable-to-contact-snap-store?rq=1

Comment: I just have to tell, that, now, for some reason, snap works. I will leave the question open though in case it happens again, or happens something different.